# How to print pdf which is in iframe using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, iframe, printing

I've tried to print a PDF, and I just tried to print it from an iframe.

HTML:

```
<iframe name="iframetoprint" id="iframetoprint" src="/path/to/mypdf.pdf"></iframe>
```

JS:

```
$('#iframetoprint').get(0).contentWindow.print();
```

and it says:

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'print' in Mozilla Firefox

I think Firefox doesn't have the permission to print PDFs from an iframe, but I have no idea.

Is there any way to do this?